# malloc showing red line

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and using C for programming. I see that there is no compilation or runtime error(I can give input and output can be displayed) but a red line appear and when I hover on red line it show me an error:
**error a value of type void * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Student*"**

Here is my code:

```
    typedef struct{
            char* firstName;
            char* lastName;
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;

        }STUDENT;

        int numStudents=3;
        int x;
    // Here it show red line, when I hover on it, it show me message
    // 
        STUDENT* students = malloc(numStudents * sizeof *students); // Here it show red line
        for (x = 0; x < numStudents; x++){
            students[x].firstName=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
            scanf("%s",students[x].firstName);
            students[x].lastName=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
            scanf("%s",students[x].lastName);
            scanf("%d",&students[x].day);
            scanf("%d",&students[x].month);
            scanf("%d",&students[x].year);
        }
for (x = 0; x < numStudents; x++)
        printf("first name: %s, surname: %s, day: %d, month: %d, year: %d\n",students[x].firstName,students[x].lastName,students[x].day,students[x].month,students[x].year);
```

Please let me know why it happens so, if there is error then it should not compile or run!!!

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: `STUDENT* students = `(STUDENT*)malloc(...);`

Comment: probably because you're compiling as c++ not C. That said you have undefined behavior immediately after because you never check to see if the allocation failed

Comment: It tells you to cast the return-value of `malloc` from `void*` to `STUDENT*` (which is usually not recommended).

Comment: Also, don't give `STUDENT` an all-uppercase name - only preprocessor macros should have uppercase names. Typedefs aren't macros.

Comment: @Mgetz Not checking the result is *not* undefined b.

Comment: @2501: but dereferencing the return value of a failed malloc is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch That is not what I was arguing against.

Comment: @Mgetz Not "check to see if the allocation failed" is not undefined behavior. Dereferencing `NULL` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably compiling as C++, and in it it is mandatory to cast a void pointer, while in C it isn't.

Tell Visual Studio to compile as C, or cast the result of malloc.